# Powershell: take cell and select only certain data from it and output it into new csv

Tags: powershell, csv

So, I have an issue with selecting data in a cell within a column full of more data than I need, and outputting only that data into a new csv.  I have a 8 column CSV that I am selecting only 2 columns from, then deleting all rows containing TCP in the Plugin Output column.  This works fine but I can't figure out the task below.

```
Import-csv c:\csv.csv | select "Plugin Output",Host | 
    Where-Object ($_."Plugin Output" -notmatch "tcp"| 
    export-csv -path C:\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

On to the next task.  Taking the Cell  stating "Remote operating system :
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Confidence Level : 99 Method : MSRPC
The remote host is running Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" in "Plugin Output" and selecting just Windows 7 out of it or Unix or Cisco..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code below to show two examples of how you should be able to go about this, one in one line and one using a multiline format with a different approach.

```
#Define any functions first
function CheckOS ([string]$CellContent) {
    switch -Wildcard ($CellContent) {
        "*windows 7*" {"Windows 7"}
        "*unix*" {"Unix"}
        "*cisco*" {"Cisco"}
        #if id doesn't match anything, return the original
        default {return $CellContent}
    }
}

#Based on your example, this will be "Windows 7"
#$OS = CheckOS $Cell

#Method 1, in one line
Import-csv c:\csv.csv | select "Plugin Output",Host | 
    Where-Object ($_."Plugin Output" -notmatch "tcp") |
    foreach-object {$_."Plugin Output" = (CheckOS $_."Plugin Output")} |
    export-csv -path C:\new.csv -NoTypeInformation

<#

#Method 2, not in one line, not using a function or switch
$CSV = Import-csv c:\csv.csv | select "Plugin Output",Host | 
    Where-Object ($_."Plugin Output" -notmatch "tcp")

#iterate through each item in the CSV
foreach ($Cell in $CSV) {
    if ($Cell."Plugin Output" -like"*windows 7*") {
        $Cell = "Windows 7"
    } elseif ($Cell."Plugin Output" -like "*unix*") {
        $Cell = "Unix"
    } elseif ($Cell."Plugin Output" -like "*cisco*") {
        $Cell = "Cisco"
    }
}

#export the csv when done
$CSV | Export-Csv -path C:\new.csv -NoTypeInformation

#>
```

Edit: I made a few errors originally. First, in method 1 I was setting it to a variable which was wrong and left over from my brain starting a different thought. In method 2 I should have been using `-like` but instead I was using `-contains` [which is wrong](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-contains).

Comment: How do I add the function to the current script I have?

Comment: If you have a .ps1 script you're using, just put the function at the top so that it gets defined first, and then when you run the script you can call it any time after that. Check out the ```Get-Help about_Functions``` [for more information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx).

Comment: I have been struggling with this...  it is my first script, and I have learned a bit in the past few days.  I add the function to the top of my current script, but I then have a problem with using the piped script

Comment: Unless you need to get everything to fit in to one line, make it easier on yourself and don't try to do everything in the pipe all at once (especially if you're writing a script). Are you trying to replace the contents of the cell before you export it to a csv?

Comment: Yes, I need all the changes to be done, and then have the changes exported to csv.  Pretty much have the OS pared out before sorting the rows.

Comment: Sure, check the above answer edit. I haven't tested it but I"m pretty sure it would work.

Comment: Thank you !  I will try it and let you know.  I'm still trying to figure it all out, but I do get what you have typed.  I was thinking about a for loop, but wasn't quite sure how to implement it.  I will try both and let you know.

Comment: I just finished method 1 and it outputs a blank CSV.. Trying method 2. then I will go back and troubleshoot method 1

Comment: And method 2 produces the same output as if there was no for loop

Comment: Try the methods again. I still haven't had a chance to test it fully, but if nothing else it's closer to an answer that should get you going. Sorry about that. If it doesn't work I'll try testing it when I get home today, or maybe someone else can provide a better answer in the meantime!

Comment: I tried again with method 2 and it failed...  I did start playing with it and this is what I did to get method 2 to work.   Modified to foreach ($_ in $CSV) { if ($_."Plugin Output" -like "*Windows*") { $_."Plugin Output" = "Windows" }